# Why is the Pali word 'saṅkhārā' in Dependent Origination plural?

Tags: pali-canon, pali-language

In researching Dependent Origination as described in [SN 12.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.2/pli/ms) and using a basic Pali language guide ([page 18](https://host.pariyatti.org/plc/EngPaliGrammar_w.audio.pdf)), I found the following about each main Pali word:

> **jarāmaraṇaṃ** singular from maraṇa neuter
>
> **jati** singular from jāti feminine
>
> **bhavo** singular from bhava masculine
>
> **upādānaṃ** singular from upādāna neuter
>
> **taṇhā** singular from taṇhā feminine
>
> **vedanā** singular from vedanā feminine
>
> **phasso** singular from phassa masculine
>
> **saḷāyatanaṃ** singular from saḷāyatana neuter
>
> **nāmarūpaṃ** singular from nāmarūpa neuter
>
> **viññāṇaṃ** singular from viññāṇa neuter
>
> **saṅkhārā** plural from saṅkhāra masculine
>
> **avijjā** singular from avijjā feminine

The above seems to correlate with every translation I have read. Note: saḷāyatanaṃ may appear to be translated as plural but it appears singular because it includes 'six'.

For example, all translations say: "*What is feeling [singular]?*" rather than "*What are feelings [plural]?*"

> And what is feeling? Katamā ca, bhikkhave, vedanā? There are these six
>   classes of feeling. Chayime, bhikkhave, vedanākāyā— Feeling born of
>   contact through the eye, ear, nose, tongue, body, and mind.
>   cakkhusamphassajā vedanā, sotasamphassajā vedanā, ghānasamphassajā
>   vedanā, jivhāsamphassajā vedanā, kāyasamphassajā vedanā,
>   manosamphassajā vedanā. This is called feeling. Ayaṃ vuccati,
>   bhikkhave, vedanā.

The saṅkhārā condition is described as follows:

> And what are **saṅkhārā [plural]**? Katame ca, bhikkhave, saṅkhārā?
>
> There are three kinds of saṅkhārā. Tayome, bhikkhave,
>   saṅkhārā— body saṅkhāro [singular], speech saṅkhāro [singular] and mind saṅkhāro
>   [singular] kāyasaṅkhāro, vacīsaṅkhāro, cittasaṅkhāro.

Why is the Pali word 'saṅkhārā' in Dependent Origination plural where all other words are singular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependent origination is the cycle of the happening event. Each event has only one decision. There are 2 saṅkhāra for each decision: wholesome and unwholesome. Wholesome saṅkhāra gives good resultants. Unwholesome saṅkhāra gives bad resultants. So, viññāna to vedanā which are the resultants of saṅkhāra must be singular, because it's just the resultants of one decision. Jāti and jarāmaraṇaṃ are same. Wholesome karmma-bhavo gives good resultants. Unwholesome karmma-bhavo gives bad resultants. So, jāti and jarāmaraṇaṃ must be singular because of the same reason.

Above explanation explained clearly in abhidhamma vibhaṅga [paccayākāravibhaṅga](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka3/v.php?B=35&A=3732&Z=3845&eng=suttacentral) and it's atthakathā. It separates each event to singular as "saṅkhāro". That's why no direct explaination in any atthakathā, included path of purification. However, **it's used widely** in difference context such as in VN.A. [Introduction](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_th.php?B=1&A=2430&w=&pagebreak=1#p116).

And this is the example of what I wrote "it's used widely":

> [Kusalattika](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka3/v.php?B=34&A=1&Z=103&eng=suttacentral): kusalā dhammā, akusalā dhammā, abyākatā dhammā.
>
> The "wholesome" triad: wholesome phenomena, unwholesome phenomena, not
>   both phenomena

The Path of Purification detailedly exposited the dependent origination follow to 'the "wholesome" triad':

> jarāmaraṇaṃ = not both phenomena
>
> jati =  not both phenomena
>
> bhavo =  not both phenomena
>
> upādānaṃ = unwholesome phenomena
>
> taṇhā =  unwholesome phenomena
>
> vedanā =  not both phenomena
>
> phasso = not both phenomena
>
> saḷāyatanaṃ =  not both phenomena
>
> nāmarūpaṃ = not both phenomena
>
> viññāṇaṃ = not both phenomena
>
> saṅkhārā = **1. wholesome phenomena, 2. unwholesome phenomena**
>
> avijjā = unwholesome phenomena

You can see whether saṅkhārā are separated into 2 events.

Above quote is my own conclusion. To read it, the reader needs to understand in advance of chapter XIV, XV, XVI, XVII, and some part of chapter I, III. Also, it requires Abhidhamma knowledge in advance, as well.

[Path of Purification](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf), CH. XVII, THE SOIL OF UNDERSTANDING—CONCLUSION, DEPENDENT ORIGINATION, III. Detailed Exposition page 547-608.

Comment: I marked this answer down because it is difficult to comprehend. Also, all conditions are unwholesome. Bhavo is unwholesome. Jati is unwholesome. 1st words of Buddha = jati is suffering.

Comment: If Upatti-Bhavo and Jati are unwholesome, there are no any arahanta, because arahanta must crease all unwholesome phenomena to be arahanta. Arahanta has **no  unwholesome phenomena**, but his current life's **suffering still going on** until he dies.

Another I modified it. I concluded it from the path of purification, as I modified above, so if you don't understand the path of purification, you can ask about it in a new topic.

Comment: To provide a better answer, i think you need to explain your key point more clearly, in the answer. Please do not add more comments. Thanks

Comment: @Dhammadhatu [How can I explain hundreds page in this topic?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2294/254) -- even harder in English. I think Bonn is saying that an answer can be found in pages 547-608 of the linked _Path_ -- that's a chapter which explains DO in detail, Chapter XVII -- and that to understand *that* you need to have understood chapters 14-16 and some part of 1 and 3.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu The bit most relevant to your question might start at near the top of page 548, i.e. "Formations" (which, is plural) -- which analyses or lists them (plural) in considerable detail.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu I too find that text daunting to summarise. And it already includes its own summary at the end of that section i.e. on starting page 577 (i.e. paragraph 182) which summarises the three kinds -- i.e. of merit, demerit, and imperturbable -- see also e.g. paragraphs 177 of page 576 "formation of merit" and other kinds of formation.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu If that doesn't answer your question I don't know what you were askng. Was it that you have another theory, a different answer to your own question already (does this answer miss some point that you were trying to make when you asked this question)?

Comment: I think its is not good enough for this site that people merely post links. If there is a salient point in the link then merely copy & paste it. Thanks

Comment: @Dhammadhatu you are the only one who never understands how it hard for Thai like me to explain something in English. You never know whether my friend, who is medico IELTS band 7.5 fluent english german chinese native thai, can't translate what I described to you neither English to Thai nor Thai to English. Many your question is very easy for me, but your restriction in language, such as no pali or no abhidhamma, let me use over long time to write the answer.

Comment: I graduated only in high school, but I read tipitaka from 16 years old. I understand pali tipiṭaka, atthakathā, and ṭikā in advance. I have many pieces of evidence on hand for you all.

Do you know if you give me the chance to write the answer mix together with pali, many question will have a very strong answer in pieces of evidence and in logic? Have you ever work as a team? Do you know the others who can't make the original answer, maybe can translate my answer into the real english? I give them the evidences and logics, they rewrte it into their own.  All my answer is free. It's teamwork.

Comment: @ChrisW Dependent origination is the cycle of the happening event. Each event has only one decision. There are 2 saṅkhāra for each decision: wholesome and unwholesome. Wholesome saṅkhāra gives good resultants. Unwholesome saṅkhāra gives bad resultants. So, viññāna to vedanā which are the resultants of saṅkhāra must be singular, because it's just the resultants of one decision. Jāti and jarāmaraṇaṃ are same. Wholesome karmma-bhavo gives good resultants. Unwholesome karmma-bhavo gives bad resultants. So, jāti and jarāmaraṇaṃ must be singular because of the same reason.

Comment: @ChrisW Above explaination explained clearly in abhidhamma vibhaṅga [paccayākāravibhaṅga](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka3/v.php?B=35&A=3732&Z=3845&eng=suttacentral) and it's atthakathā. It separates each event to singular as "saṅkhāro". That's why no direct explaination in any atthakathā, included path of purification. However, it's used widely in difference context such as http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_th.php?B=1&A=2430&w=&pagebreak=1#p116.

Comment: OK. I scored your answer up (even though I do not necessarily agree with it). You explained why sankhara is plural and why the others are singular in terms of "each decision" or "each event". I understood what you were attempting to explain. Thank you. Khop Kun Krap Khun Bonn.

Answer (score 0):

Disappointing there has only been one attempt to answer this question. Often questions are asked about if only one sense organ can operate at the same time therefore I expected some interest in this question.

The impression is each link (except sankhara) allows for the common arising of one type of phenomena in a moment. For example, eye contact being the predominant experience or sensual attachment being the predominant experience or sensual becoming being the predominant experience.

However, with sankhara, the impression is all three sankhara (namely, kaya, vaci & citta sankhara) can arise together, at the same time.