# Why is the Pali word 'sattānaṃ' in Dependent Origination plural?

Tags: pali-canon, pali-language

In this previous [question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/30162/why-is-the-pali-word-sa%E1%B9%85kh%C4%81r%C4%81-in-dependent-origination-plural), I listed the results of my investigations into how each nidana (link) in dependent origination appears to be 'singular', except 'sankhara', which is plural.

The 'jati' ('birth') link also appears to be singular. However, what is unusual about it is the singular 'birth' that occurs appears to have 'plural' components. It is translated as follows by Bhikkhus Bodhi, Thanissaro & Sujato:

> *Katamā ca, bhikkhave, jāti (singular)? Yā tesaṃ tesaṃ sattānaṃ (plural) tamhi tamhi sattanikāye (plural) jāti sañjāti okkanti abhinibbatti khandhānaṃ
>   pātubhāvo āyatanānaṃ paṭilābho.*
>
> *And what, bhikkhus, is birth? The birth of the various **beings** (**sattānaṃ**) into the various orders of beings, their being born, descent, production,
>   the manifestation of the aggregates, the obtaining of the sense bases.
>   This is called birth. (Bodhi)*
>
> *And what is birth? Whatever birth, taking birth, descent, coming-to-be, coming-forth, appearance of aggregates, & acquisition of
>   [sense] media of the various beings in this or that group of beings,
>   that is called birth (Thanissaro).*
>
> *The rebirth, inception, conception, **reincarnation**, manifestation of the aggregates, and acquisition of the sense fields of the various
>   sentient beings in the various orders of sentient beings. (Sujato)*

Now, each link of Dependent Origination appears to apply to the sense experience of an individual. Or, alternately, the Buddhaghosa interpretation over 3 lifetimes appears to be about the reincarnation of an individual.

This being so, why does 'birth' ('jati'), seemingly a singular process, seem to refer to the birth (yā jati) of multiple beings (sattānaṃ) into the multiple orders/groups of beings (sattanikāye)? Why is the plural Pali word 'sattānaṃ' contained in the definition of what appears to be a singular process called 'jati' ('birth') in Dependent Origination?

Answer (score 6):

> why does 'birth' ('jati'), seemingly a singular process, seem to refer to the multiple births of multiple beings into the multiple orders/groups of beings?

*jāti* is singular in the passage quoted, so it is not referring to multiple births. *sattanikaye* is also singular, so "in this or that group of beings".

> Why is the plural Pali word 'sattānaṃ' contained in the definition of what appears to be a singular process called 'jati' ('birth') in Dependent Origination?

*tesaṃ tesaṃ sattānaṃ* is not an ordinary plural, the duplicated pronoun means "of these or those", so the whole phrase means "whatever birth (singular) in this or that being-group of these or those beings".

it were to mean "the multiple births of multiple beings" as you suggest, *jāti* would have to be plural, which it isn't; *yā jāti* refers to a singular birth.

The commentary to this clause says:

> **yā tesaṃ tesaṃ sattānan** ti idaṃ “imesaṃ nāmā”ti niyamābhāvato sabbasattānaṃ pariyādānavacanaṃ.

Which I translated roughly as:

> **yā tesaṃ tesaṃ sattānaṃ**: this phrase is the taking up completely of all beings, from not specifying "of these only"

In other words, it is used to make clear that birth is not specific to one or another group of beings, but refers to birth in any group of beings.

In summary, the entire phrase appears simply to be saying that birth refers to any of the many kinds of birth in any of the many groups of beings that exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bhikkhu. Yes, "ya jati" is singular. I always knew this so I will modify the question slightly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avijjā and saṅkhāra of **a past** aggregates' rebirth cause **a present** aggregates' rebirth, present taṅhā&upādāna&kamma-bhava cause **a future** aggregates' rebirth. So, rebirth is singular is right.
2. It is "each being's rebirth of any beings in any being type".

It's [similar to English](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95508/237959) "one of **them** go by **bus**". You can't say "one of **him** go by **A** bus".

> Yā tesaṃ tesaṃ sattānaṃ (plural) tamhi tamhi sattanikāye (plural) jāti sañjāti okkanti abhinibbatti khandhānaṃ pātubhāvo āyatanānaṃ paṭilābho.
>
> **Each** (yā) **rebirth** (jāti) **of any** (tesaṃ tesaṃ) **beings** (sattānaṃ) in any (taṃhi taṃhi) being type (sattanikāye) **is** **jāti**, *sañjāti, okkanti, abhinibbatti* (all is the synonym of rebirth), *khandhānaṃ pātubhāvo* (rebirth of viñnāna&nāma&rūpa in the dependent origination), *āyatanānaṃ paṭilābho* (the obtaining of saḷāyatanas in the dependent origination because of that rebirth).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to his question is found in Wikipedia; however, since Buddhism has become distorted since the Buddha; the Wikipedia answer now falls under Hinduism:

> *Jāti (in Devanagari: जाति, Bengali: জাতি, Telugu:జాతి, Kannada:ಜಾತಿ, Malayalam: ജാതി, Tamil:ஜாதி, literally "birth") is a group of clans,
>   tribes, communities, and sub-communities, and religions in India. Each
>   Jāti typically has an association with a traditional job function or
>   tribe. Religious beliefs (e.g. Sri Vaishnavism or Veera Shaivism) or
>   linguistic groupings may define some Jātis. A person's surname
>   typically reflects a community (Jāti) association: thus Gandhi =
>   perfume seller, Dhobi = washerman, Srivastava = military scribe, etc.*
>
> *Wikipedia*

Since MN 98 says all differences among human beings are merely "verbal designations" and since SN 23.2 and SN 5.10 say "a being" ('satta') is merely a "view" or "clinging", it appears obvious "birth" ("jati") in Dependent Origination refers to how a single mind gives birth to different views and categories of "people" or "beings".

Also, since the standard teaching of Dependent Origination (in SN 12.2) contains no teachings about "kamma" (such as found in AN 6.63), it is obvious Dependent Origination (in SN 12.2; unlike the dodgy DN 15) is not referring to physical birth as a "human", "god", "animal", "ghost", "hell being", etc.

In short, the reason why "jati" is singular yet "beings" are plural appears to be because "jati" refers to how the individual ignorant mind produces the various views & categories of "people", "beings" or "self-entites".

Examples of these produced "beings within categories of beings" include: good man, bad man, short man, tall man, good woman, bad woman, attractive woman, ugly woman, good monk, bad monks, obese monk, enlightened monk, etc. All of these specific individual beings and the categories or groups of beings they fall into are mind made; made from ignorance.

Note: Only one "being" is produced in each mind moment.

Thich Nhat Hanh provided a clear description of this, when he asked: "*What do you call me without a pen?*" Answer: "*A monk*". Then: "*what do you call me when you see me drawing calligraphy with a paint brush?*" Answer: "*A calligrapher*". The category of "being" called a "calligrapher" arises from the "appearance or manifestation" of aggregates (khandhānaṃ pātubhāvo) in a different way.

Comment: Interested in why you said, "unlike the dodgy DN 15". What do you find problematic in that sutta?

Comment: Hi Linda. Good to see you again. What is dodgy about DN 15? It only includes 9 conditions and only 8 conditions of DO are defined. Death is not defined. Jati is defined differently to the other suttas, which define birth, aging & death as pertaining to "beings in a class of beings". The word "beings" refer to self-views (SN 5.10; SN 23.2). DN 15 is not clear about this, whether birth is biological or whether it is a self-view. DN 15 does not refer to the six sense bases. DN 15 is obviously a later text, unlike SN 12.2 which redefines nama-rupa from the Sama Veda (early Chandogya Upanishad)...

Comment: .... DN 15 includes a definition of namarupa from the later Brihadaranyaka Upanishad. Then DN 15 has the very strange & late concept of consciousness entering the mother's womb. The notion of consciousness entering a mothers womb is only found in few & obviously late suttas, such as MN 123 (Jataka style) and two DNs about entering mothers womb with or without sati-sampajana. Also, while DN 15 later refers explicitly to the consciousness of a boy or girl; it is actually uncertain what consciousness is entering the mother's womb because it could be the mother's consciousness descending into...

Comment: ...her womb to name the rupa in her womb as "my child", "my boy", "my girl". Since DN 15 certainly contains supramundane teacings about delineating self-views, it is possible this is the meaning of consciousness entering the mother's womb, namely, the mother generating nama-rupa (per Brihadaranyaka Upanishad meaning) towards the child in her womb. But the use of mothter's womb (mātukucchismiṁ) in the Suttas seems to rule this out. Sujato wrote an excellent intro to the DN, where i recall he suggested either the lateness of the DN or otherwise its purpose to preach to, convert & debate Brahmins

Comment: The bottom line is namarupa has an Upanashadic definition & namarupa & consciousness are supposed to be mutual conditions for eachother. Yet in reality if the consciousness entering into the mother's womb is a disembodied consciousness from a past life than how does this explicitly condition the naming of forms (namarupa)? A translation says: "If consciousness were not to descend into the mother’s womb, would mentality-materiality take shape in the womb?" This idea is nonsense. Namarupa is defined as the naming of forms & obviously per MN 64 an embryo is not doing this in a womb.

Comment: Sujato's DN intro https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/the-long-discourses-dhamma-as-literature-and-compilation/11523

Comment: Thanks. I used to find DN 15 dodgy too, but then two things happened. First, I deconstructed Sn 4.11 ("Quarrels and Disputes") and therein found the Buddha describing DA as all about, well, quarrels and disputes, making it very close to what's being said in DN 15. (My paper on it is available elsewhere on the Net.) And second, I noticed that DN 15 -- in which the Buddha is talking just to his cousin and close companion Ananda -- uses the word *pariyāya* eighteen times. It gets glossed over in translations as "the way to explain" but it more literally means "figuratively".

Comment: I now perceive DN 15 as a transitional sutta, between Sn 4.11's rendering of DA with dukkha as arguments and violence, and the Buddha reframing the same lesson in terms of rebirth -- the Prajapati creation myth, the rituals based on it, and what comes after death. In DN 15 he tries to hammer into Ananda that he's speaking figuratively, not literally, about descent into the womb, etc.  Blog post on this here: https://justalittledust.com/blog/?p=1439